# MATLAB code for multiple work done automatically

Tags: matlab-guide

I want to create a MATLAB code that will create a database of images and when a image is given as input it will search the database and match the given input.After that it will command a microcontroller. I want to know how I'll be able to do the whole thing automatically.The loop will run automatically.

Comment: I want to create a project based on face recognition for voting system. I want to do it with MATLAB and microcontroller. But don't know how to connect all in one.

Comment: SO isn't the best place to come for ideas when you haven't even started yet. [Please read](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have started.what I want to know that how I will be able to do the whole work in a single command at MATLAB.